# Chrome adds all bookmarks to Other Bookmarks folder

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

I have a problem with Chrome that started a couple days ago. I don't know if this issue came with an update, I just know that it started happening. I'm on Windows 8.1, Chrome version 40.0.2214.94 m.

My bookmarks icon has changed to be a flat gray color with no outline instead of the previous outlined white design. I assume this is a Material Design thing, no big deal. However, clicking that bookmark button in the past would pop up a small box allowing me to change the name, edit the link, choose the folder, etc. Now, however, I see a box pop up for a split second (too short a time to actually see what it is), then the bookmark is immediately added to the "Other Bookmarks" folder on my bookmarks toolbar.

Is this a new "feature" of Chrome? Is there a way I can restore the old functionality?

Comment: When you save a link a popup opens, there is a "folder" drop down box to change the folder location, it just saves it by default to the last place you saved one, you can change the location and then hit Done button.

Comment: As I stated in the post, that box only pops up for a split second before it disappears. I cannot make the selection in the box as I have in the past.

Comment: Back up your bookmarks, uninstall chrome completely, then re-install the latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out the answer to this. This is part of Chrome's new enhanced bookmarks system. I'm on the stable channel, so it shouldn't have been enabled for me, but I force-disabled it at chrome://flags/#enhanced-bookmarks-experiment. Bookmarks now work properly again.